# Editing part of a specific line in a text file in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to edit a text file.
If my text has less than X lines, I want to add X-1 empty lines and then the line I want to add (for example a variable called my_addition).
If the text has x or more lines, I need to edit them and add my_addition.
Text for example:

```
text:text:text: * (X-1 lines)
my_addition:text:text: (line number X)
```

Comment: Where's your attempt?

Comment: Show us part of your code, And explain more clearly

Answer (score 0):

You could read the file as an array of lines and modify the last line, then write the modified lines back to the file.

```
with open("my_file.txt", "r") as f:     # Open the file in read mode
    lines = f.read().splitlines()       # Get lines as an array
    lines[-1] = "Hello" + lines[-1]     # Add your additon to the last line

with open("my_file.txt", "w") as f:     # open the file in write mode
    for line in lines:
        f.write("%s\n" % line)          # write each line to file
```